# For loop not working in booking site, the dates are not serial

Tags: html, loops

I was trying to make a booking site, then a problem occured that the for loop is working or my logic is wrong.

I was expecting (screenshot of an older version of the code):

[image]

What the output was (screenshot of the new version):

[image]

Also I am using PHP for this and the `check_date.php` is working as intended.  Something is wrong probably when I try to make the AJAX request.

```js
// JavaScript code for generating the calendar and handling month navigation
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById("calendar");
const prevMonthBtn = document.getElementById("prevMonth");
const nextMonthBtn = document.getElementById("nextMonth");
const currentMonthYear = document.getElementById("currentMonthYear");

const daysOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
const months = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const currentDate = new Date();
let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

function generateCalendar() {
  const daysInMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
  const firstDayIndex = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay();

  calendarContainer.innerHTML = "";

  // Display days of the week at the top of the calendar
  for (const dayOfWeek of daysOfWeek) {
    const dayOfWeekDiv = document.createElement("div");
    dayOfWeekDiv.classList.add("day");
    dayOfWeekDiv.textContent = dayOfWeek;
    calendarContainer.appendChild(dayOfWeekDiv);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < firstDayIndex; i++) {
    const dayDiv = document.createElement("div");
    dayDiv.classList.add("day");
    calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    const dayDiv = document.createElement("a");
    dayDiv.href = "entry.php";
    let __ryear = currentYear.toString();
    let __rmonth = currentMonth.toString();
    let daI = i.toString();
    let result1 = __ryear.concat(__rmonth);
    let result2 = result1.concat(daI);
    // let ruiue = result2;
    // let date6969 = i;

    // AJAX request to check if the date exists in the database
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/irctclogin/check_date.php?date=" + result2, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        let response = xhr.responseText;
        if (response == "exists") {

          // Date exists in the database, continue the program
          let bookStatus = "booked";
          dayDiv.classList.add("day", result2, bookStatus);
          dayDiv.textContent = i;
          calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
          // dayDiv.value = i;

        }
          else {
            let bookStatus = "available";
            dayDiv.classList.add("day", result2, bookStatus);
            dayDiv.textContent = i;
            calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
            // dayDiv.value = i;
            // console.log(i);
          }
        }
      }
      xhr.send();
    }

    currentMonthYear.textContent = `${months[currentMonth]} ${currentYear}`;
    // console.log(`${months[currentMonth]} ${currentYear}`);
  }

  prevMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentMonth === 0) {
      currentMonth = 11;
      currentYear--;
    } else {
      currentMonth--;
    }
    generateCalendar();
  });

  nextMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentMonth === 11) {
      currentMonth = 0;
      currentYear++;
    } else {
      currentMonth++;
    }
    generateCalendar();
  });

  generateCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your days are appearing out of order is because they are generated in the order that your AJAX requests complete.  Just because you fire off multiple AJAX requests in order, it does not mean that they will complete in the same order that you started them.  So if request #10 finishes before request #9, your 10th of the month cell will appear before your 9th.

Here's a working snippet with some very basic CSS with your AJAX commented out, which shows that generating the calendar works fine without the AJAX.

```js
const calendarContainer = document.getElementById("calendar");

const daysOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
const months     = [
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const currentDate = new Date();
let currentMonth  = currentDate.getMonth();
let currentYear   = currentDate.getFullYear();

function generateCalendar() {
    const daysInMonth   = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
    const firstDayIndex = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay();

    calendarContainer.innerHTML = "";

    // Display days of the week at the top of the calendar
    for (const dayOfWeek of daysOfWeek) {
        const dayOfWeekDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dayOfWeekDiv.classList.add("day");
        dayOfWeekDiv.textContent = dayOfWeek;
        calendarContainer.appendChild(dayOfWeekDiv);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < firstDayIndex; i++) {
        const dayDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dayDiv.classList.add("day");
        calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        const dayDiv = document.createElement("a");
        dayDiv.href  = "entry.php";
        let __ryear  = currentYear.toString();
        let __rmonth = currentMonth.toString();
        let daI      = i.toString();
        let result1  = __ryear.concat(__rmonth);
        let result2  = result1.concat(daI);

        // AJAX request to check if the date exists in the database
        // let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/irctclogin/check_date.php?date=" + result2, true);
        // xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        //     let response = xhr.responseText;
        //     if (response == "exists") {
        //
        //       // Date exists in the database, continue the program
        //       let bookStatus = "booked";
        //       dayDiv.classList.add("day", result2, bookStatus);
        //       dayDiv.textContent = i;
        //       calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
        //       // dayDiv.value = i;
        //
        //     }
        //       else {
                let bookStatus = "available";
                dayDiv.classList.add("day", result2, bookStatus);
                dayDiv.textContent = i;
                calendarContainer.appendChild(dayDiv);
        //         // dayDiv.value = i;
        //         // console.log(i);
        //       }
        //     }
        //   }
        //   xhr.send();
    }
}

generateCalendar();
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

A much better approach is to generate your calendar independent of your AJAX, on page load say, just as an empty template waiting for data.  You are already giving each cell a unique class based on the date (`result2` in your code).  So when you get an AJAX result for 23rd July, 2023, you can find the cell you need to update with a selector like:

```
// Say your AJAX returns some data with a value like 'date"
let cell = document.getElementsByClassName(date);
cell.classList.add('booked');
```

But firing a separate AJAX request for every day in the month is terribly inefficient - it is going to take a long time to finish the month, and it seems like a high chance some requests won't complete or will be refused.  31 requests in a fraction of a second seems like a good way to get blocked for looking like a bot.

A much better option would be for your AJAX to return data for an entire month at once.  You'll have to update your PHP obviously, and return data in a format that can represent multiple days, each with a booking state.  For example:

```
// Your PHP code, inside some kind of loop here, iterating over days in the month ..

$month[] = [
    'date'  => $date,
    'state' => $state // 'booked' or whatever ...
];

// Loop finished, now return data as JSON

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($month);
```

Now your Javascript can process the entire month with 1 AJAX call.  You just need to iterate over the JSON response and update each cell with the right status.